# certificate default path in windows

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, filesystems, scanning

When scanning a file system host to found its SSL certificates and the customer does not give the path of this system file (for Linux , I chosen /etc because , generally all ssl certificate are under this directory, for windows what default path should I choose?

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/411909/where-is-the-certificate-folder-in-windows-7) answer your question? You can also check `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\`, but as the answers to that question point out you may be missing a lot of certificates in this way.